# iOS7 Pass data backward by protocol at Navigation controller push view setting

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller

I tried many custom delegate examples in my code to send data from view B back to parent view A.  Why am I getting NULL?  There should be something I am missing.  Please help.  How can I call setupDate to receive (NSDate *)setAlarmDate in Parent view?

Parent view

```
#import "SetupViewController.h"

@interface ViewController : UIViewController <SetupViewControllerDelegate> {
NSTimer *timer;
}
@end

#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController
-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender{
if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"setupview"]) {
    NSLog(@"prepare for segue");
    SetupViewController *svc = [[SetupViewController alloc] init];
    svc.delegate = self;

-(void)setupDate:(NSDate *)setAlarmDate{
NSLog(@"Hey Hey");
NSLog(@"%@", setAlarmDate);
}
@end
```

View B

```
@protocol SetupViewControllerDelegate <NSObject>
@required
-(void)setupDate:(NSDate *)setAlarmDate;
@end

@interface SetupViewController : UIViewController
@property (nonatomic, strong) id <SetupViewControllerDelegate> delegate;
//IB
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIDatePicker *pDatePicker;
@end
```

.m

```
#import "SetupViewController.h"
#import "ViewController.h"
@implementation SetupViewController
-(void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated{
NSDate *date = [self.pDatePicker date];
[[self delegate] setupDate:date];
}
@end
```

Comment: in viewWillDisappear:animated your delegate is nil? Moreover any delegate should has weak attribute. You should also check if your delegate respondsToSelector to avoid potential crashes

Comment: @Neru made it to weak.  thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should access the `UIViewController` using the segue's `destinationViewController` property instead of allocating an instance of your own, which is why your `alarmDate = NULL`.

**E.g.**

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"setupview"])
    {
        NSLog(@"prepare for segue");
        SetupViewController *svc = [segue destinationViewController];
        svc.delegate = self;
    }
}
```

Also, as @Neru mentioned your delegate should be qualified as weak and not strong. The reason for this is because you will cause a retain cycle if you do not explicitly set the `delegate = nil` in the dealloc method.

Comment: Yes!! It worked.  Thanks.  sec with segue destinationViewController fixed this.  I totally misunderstood what it meant by instantiating a view controller in self.  Thanks.